# How can I get this code involving unique_ptr to compile?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, unique-ptr

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    A(): i(new int) {}
    A(A const& a) = delete;
    A(A &&a): i(move(a.i)) {}

    unique_ptr<int> i;
};

class AGroup {
public:
    void                    AddA(A &&a) { a_.emplace_back(move(a)); }

    vector<A> a_;
};

int main() {
    AGroup ag;
    ag.AddA(A());
    return 0;
}
```

does not compile... (says that unique_ptr's copy constructor is deleted)

I tried replacing move with forward.  Not sure if I did it right, but it didn't work for me.

---

```
[~/nn/src] g++ a.cc -o a -std=c++0x
/opt/local/include/gcc44/c++/bits/unique_ptr.h: In member function 'A& A::operator=(const A&)':
a.cc:6:   instantiated from 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Tp_alloc_type::pointer, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc> >, _Args&& ...) [with _Args = A, _Tp = A, _Alloc = std::allocator<A>]'
/opt/local/include/gcc44/c++/bits/vector.tcc:100:   instantiated from 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::emplace_back(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = A, _Tp = A, _Alloc = std::allocator<A>]'
a.cc:17:   instantiated from here
/opt/local/include/gcc44/c++/bits/unique_ptr.h:219: error: deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Tp_Deleter>& std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Tp_Deleter>::operator=(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Tp_Deleter>&) [with _Tp = int, _Tp_Deleter = std::default_delete<int>]'
a.cc:6: error: used here
In file included from /opt/local/include/gcc44/c++/vector:69,
                 from a.cc:1:
/opt/local/include/gcc44/c++/bits/vector.tcc: In member function 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Tp_alloc_type::pointer, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc> >, _Args&& ...) [with _Args = A, _Tp = A, _Alloc = std::allocator<A>]':
/opt/local/include/gcc44/c++/bits/vector.tcc:100:   instantiated from 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::emplace_back(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = A, _Tp = A, _Alloc = std::allocator<A>]'
a.cc:17:   instantiated from here
/opt/local/include/gcc44/c++/bits/vector.tcc:314: note: synthesized method 'A& A::operator=(const A&)' first required here
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably your standard library doesn't (yet) define `unique_ptr<T>::unique_ptr(unique_ptr &&)`. I checked my headers in 4.5 and it's there, so maybe try upgrading.

When it fails to find the move constructor, it would look for the copy constructor and find it deleted.

I get other errors when I compile that, though.

**EDIT:** Got it to work. I don't understand why you have to `move` an object which is already an rvalue reference, but you do. The only problem was a missing assigment operator.

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    A(): i(new int) {}
    A(A const& a) = delete;
    A &operator=(A const &) = delete;
    A(A &&a): i(move(a.i)) {}
    A &operator=(A &&a ) { i = move(a.i); }

    unique_ptr<int> i;
};

class AGroup {
public:
    void                    AddA(A &&a) { a_.emplace_back(move(a)); }

    vector<A> a_;
};

int main() {
    AGroup ag;
    ag.AddA(A());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow!  I am so thankful for your solution.  This was frustrating me to no end.

Comment: Tested your solution and it works.

I really wish that operator= defaulted to using the matching copy constructor.  Maybe with `auto concepts`, they will?

Comment: You probably know more about that than me; I solved this by being an error-message jockey.

Comment: a named rvalue reference (like `a`) is actually an lvalue which makes `std::move` necessary.